# What's the advantage of having multi-line & single-line string literals in python?

Tags: python, string, literals, string-literals, docstring

I know the triple quote strings are used as docstrings, but is there a real need to have two string literals?

Are there any use case when identifying between single-line & multi-line is useful.

in Clojure we have 1 string literal, is multi-line and we use it as docstring. So why the difference in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of having to be explicit about creating a multi-line string literal is probably best demonstrated with an example:

```
with open("filename.ext) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.upper())
```

Of course, any decent syntax-highlighting editor will catch that, but:

1. It isn't always the case that you're using a syntax-highlighting editor
2. Python has no control over what editor you *are* using.

Two of Python's design principles are that

- errors should never pass silently, and
- explicit is better than implicit.

Outside docstrings, multi-line strings are rarely used in Python, so the example above is much more likely to occur (everyone mistypes sometimes) than the case where you want a multi-line string, but forgot to explicitly say so by triple-quoting.

It's similar to Python's use of significant whitespace, in that enforcing good, consistent indentation practice means that errors are much more easily caught than in e.g. a brace-delimited language.

Comment: Of course, even StackOverflow is smart enough to notice this mistake and highlight the whole thing as string :)

Comment: Anyone who's ever spent days tracking down a bug cares *a great deal* about the things that happen 0.01% of the time.

Comment: Multi-line strings are also useful for embedding data and code in scripts, such as for doctests as shown this classic recipe for [`namedtuples`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/).

Comment: Not having highlighting it is a big deal and really painful, so i get it now, the fact the triple quotes are so noisy, really annoying to me to the point i'm writing an emacs extension to solve it. This reminded me of trigraphs in C, for the case your keyboard didn't have the special characters in the times previous to hardware standardization.

Comment: And for the significant whitespace or offside rule, doesn't hide bugs also, like with copy/paste or an accidental typing and removing or adding some indentation? 

In the case of any grouping syntax () or "" [] or {} or <> or any other, i always close it right after open it. to avoid those mistypings. Of course when dealing with other's code i might find the bug.